# Java (ElasticSearch) - build query due to the many fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I use Java and Java High Level REST Client.
I need to build query that will find documents. This query should contain many fields for searching.
For example, I have such json:

```
{
  "timeStamp": "Fri, 29 Dec 2017 15:32:22 +0000",
  "value": 314,
  "operation": "http://software-testing.ru/library/testing/testing-tools/2638-postman",
  "type": "duration",
  "system": "front-admin"
}
```

and I need find all document due to the all fields.
I understand how constract query due to the one field (parametr) but don't know how I can use a lot of fields for query:

```
@PostMapping("/findMetricsByValues") @Transactional public ResponseEntity findMetricsByValues(@RequestBody ElasticSearchMetrics metrics){

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();

    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("value",  metrics.getValue()));
    searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
    try {
        searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new GenericResponse(searchResponse, CODE_200), HttpStatus.OK); }
```

Could somebody help with it or give a hint?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(String query) method instead
   In this you can write query according to may fields
   Below is a link that can help you with this ->
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-query-string-query.html
   There are many clauses like AND , OR for joining multiple queries.
   Here is syntax for writing query in a string -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax
2. You can use bool query -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-bool-query.html